# Vertically align table-cell element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style an aligned html form with display: table* CSS properties. Now I'm using something like this:

```css
.form-aligned {
  display: table;
}
.form-aligned label {
  display: table-row;
}
.form-aligned .label {
  width: 100px;
}
.form-aligned .label,
.form-aligned input,
.form-aligned .error {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-aligned">
  <label>
    <span class="label">Age</span>
    <input/>
    <span class="error">Must be a number between 1 and 199</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span class="label">Last or First or Whatever name</span>
    <input/>
    <span class="error">Be serious please</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

It works perfectly but when label is too long (like in second input), input element is aligned to the top of the row. It looks a bit ugly. I would like an input to align in the middle of the row. But I can't figure out how to achieve that.

I tried to use `vertical-align: middle`, but it doesn't seem to work.

If I enclose an input into container, it'll work. But that's extra markup which I would like to avoid.

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oab5hbqo/1/ , below is a real table with correct `vertical-align` behaviour (what I'm trying to achieve with CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` are [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) which can't be displayed (on most browsers) as `table-cell`.

In fact, if it was displayed as `table-cell`, it would grow to cover all row's height. That is, the height of a table cell is the same as the height of the table row, so there is no point in centering a table cell vertically.

So you must use a container, or think a non-tabular approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline-flex` for this

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oab5hbqo/5/

Here is all of the css:

```
.form-aligned label {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-aligned .label {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
span, input {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't read "*If I enclose an input into container, it'll work. But that's extra markup which I would like to avoid.*".

Comment: Oops look like I did miss that part